# How to Solve WordPress Login in Local Host?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I have set up WordPress on my XAMPP control panel and all the installation issues going well, and I got access as admin to my dashboard for the first time. My problem now, I can not reach the Login Page, and the page appears as the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding /wp-admin to the end of your URL

Comment: I got this (Internal Server Error) !!